# Rails 5 - Link associated tables in query that is joined through another table with includes method

Tags: model-associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to add an associated table to a query that is joined through another table.  For example below, I would like to include facility (though I know it is not valid syntax).

`Actual` belongs to `Encounter` and `Encounter` belongs to `Facility`. (The `Actual` table has an `encounter_id` field, and the `Encounters` table has a `facility_id` field.)

**Sudo Code:**

```
respond_with(Actual.where(:encounter_id => params[:encounter_id]),
                  :include => [:encounter, :encounter.facility])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
respond_with(Actual.where(encounter_id: params[:encounter_id]).includes(encounter: :facility))
```

Comment: Leandroico - that doesn't seem to work. With that, the encounters and facilities are not showing ...just actual. thanks

Comment: What response format is that? JSON? In that case I recommend you to use this gem: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers. The line of code above you'll just spare you from making extra SQL queries for each association. You need a serializer to explicit tell what data will be exposed in the response.

Comment: What kind of return were you expecting from something like `Actual.where(encounter_id: params[:encounter_id]).includes(encounter: :facility)`? A Hash? An Array? In the end, you'll always get an `ActiveRecord::Base` instance, from which you can access the associations specified without performing extra SQL queries. That's the thing.